# How to perform an 'su' in a Haskell (web) application

Tags: unix, haskell, authentication, passwords

I'm writing a Yesod-based application and it would be useful to allow, as an option, authentication via the same means as a local 'su';  that is to say:  the user supplies the login name and password and the session effectively performs an 'su' with those credentials and runs with the same permissions as would the user logged-in locally on the machine.  This is because one deployment scenario has the web application accessing and manipulating files in the user's $HOME.  However, the lack of an API for the purpose leads me to conclude that what I want is infeasible or nonsensical for some reason.  The closest I could find was a crypt() function but (1) it requires a salt and (2) /etc/shadow is only readable by root.  I was expecting some function like:

```
setEffUId :: String -> String -> IO (Either SomeError Bool)
```

Presumably someone would have written this is if it were feasible to do so, so why isn't it ?

Comment: Keep in mind that unix does not allow a process to _raise_ its permissions. setuid/seteuid can change the uid of the current process only if (very roughly) the current uid is root, or if you are just "moving" uids between uid and euid. The OS itself never checks passwords, su does, and since su is run as root it can setuid to the right user.

Answer (score 2):

The package [unix](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.1.0/docs/System-Posix-User.html#v:setEffectiveUserID) has a similar function related to what you want:

```
setEffectiveUserID :: UserID -> IO ()
```

The function seems to be implemented via FFI. That being said, I don't think it is a good idea to use `su` based thing from Yesod. Also, seeing the above API, I guess it will only work when invoked from a higher privilege.

Comment: That definitely won't do what I want because it doesn't take a password as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't make sense in Yesod is because Warp doesn't spawn a new process for every connection (at least not by default).

In this situation: you should use a separate program that does all the per-user operations and call it with one of the functions from `System.Process`